# To find records from Table A having effective dates closest to records in table B

Tags: sql, oracle, closest

I have  two tables as below:

Table A:

| ID | Age | Dept | Salary | Start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | A | $1000 | 01-01-2000 |
| 1 | 31 | B | $1200 | 01-01-2022 |
| 2 | 25 | C | $1200 | 01-06-2021 |
| 2 | 26 | A | $1300 | 01-01-2022 |
| 3 | 34 | D | $1400 | 01-01-2021 |
| 3 | 35 | C | $1800 | 01-01-2022 |

Table B:

| ID | Salary | Start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $1500 | 01-06-2022 |
| 2 | $1800 | 01-01-2022 |
| 3 | $1600 | 01-06-2021 |

I want to insert synthetic new records in Table A, when there is a mismatch in ID and start_date combination between Table A and Table B. The new record should get the Age & Dept from table A for the record which has the closest start date from the missing record in Table B, and salary and start date from table B.

**Output:**

| ID | Age | Dept | Salary | Start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | A | $1000 | 01-01-2000 |
| 1 | 31 | B | $1200 | 01-01-2022 |
| 1 | 31 | B | $1500 | 01-06-2022 |
| 2 | 25 | C | $1200 | 01-06-2021 |
| 2 | 26 | A | $1300 | 01-01-2022 |
| 3 | 34 | D | $1400 | 01-01-2021 |
| 3 | 34 | D | $1600 | 01-06-2021 |
| 3 | 35 | C | $1500 | 01-01-2022 |

Please help to write SQL queries which will achieve this.

I am facing problems in identifying the rows from Table A which has the closest start_date from the records in Table B.

Comment: “*Please help to write SQL queries which will achieve this.*” We can help, but only really if you can show us your best attempt as a [mre] with an explanation of where *specifically* you’re getting stuck. See also [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` to combine the two tables and then the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function to get the most recent `age` and `dept` values when they are not present:

```sql
SELECT id,
       LAST_VALUE(age) IGNORE NULLS
         OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date) AS age,
       LAST_VALUE(dept) IGNORE NULLS
         OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date) AS dept,
       salary,
       start_date
FROM   (
  SELECT id, age, dept, salary, start_date
  FROM   table_a
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, NULL, NULL, salary, start_date
  FROM   table_b
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (ID, Age, Dept, Salary, Start_date) AS
SELECT 1, 30, 'A', 1000, DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 31, 'B', 1200, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 25, 'C', 1200, DATE '2021-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 26, 'A', 1300, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 34, 'D', 1400, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 35, 'C', 1800, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table_B (ID, Salary, Start_date) AS
SELECT 1, 1500, DATE '2022-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1800, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1600, DATE '2021-06-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | AGE | DEPT | SALARY | START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | A | 1000 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 31 | B | 1200 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 31 | B | 1500 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 25 | C | 1200 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 26 | A | 1300 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 26 | A | 1800 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 34 | D | 1400 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 34 | D | 1600 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 35 | C | 1800 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |

---

If you want to `INSERT` the missing rows then, from Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join and `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` to find the most recent `age` and `dept` values for each row of `table_b`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_a (id, age, dept, salary, start_date)
SELECT b.id, a.age, a.dept, b.salary, b.start_date
FROM   table_b b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT a.age, a.dept
         FROM   table_a a
         WHERE  a.id = b.id
         AND    a.start_date <= b.start_date
         ORDER BY start_date DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) a
       ON 1 = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vyO227Vg)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right - just the rows without matching ID, START_DATE combination (in both tables) should be added. That means the row with ID = 2  in table B will not affect the matching row in table A. If that is the case than you need a combination of union all from the tables and Row_Number() and Last_Value() analytic functions along with some Case expressions.

```sql
WITH        --  Sample Data
    tbl_a (ID, AGE, DEPT, SALARY, START_DATE) AS
        (   Select 1, 30, 'A', 1000, DATE '2000-01-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 31, 'B', 1200, DATE '2022-01-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 25, 'C', 1200, DATE '2021-06-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 26, 'A', 1300, DATE '2022-01-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 34, 'D', 1400, DATE '2021-01-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 35, 'C', 1800, DATE '2022-01-01' From Dual
        ),
    tbl_b (ID, SALARY, START_DATE) AS
        (   Select 1, 1500, DATE '2022-06-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 1800, DATE '2022-01-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 1600, DATE '2021-06-01' From Dual
        )
--  
--  M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    ID, 
          Case  When AGE Is Not Null Then AGE
          Else LAST_VALUE(AGE) OVER(Partition By ID Order By ID, START_DATE, TBL Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding) 
          End "AGE",
          --
          Case  When DEPT Is Not Null Then DEPT 
          Else LAST_VALUE(DEPT) OVER(Partition By ID Order By ID, START_DATE, TBL Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding)
          End "DEPT",
          --
          SALARY "SALARY", START_DATE "START_DATE"
FROM      ( Select    * 
            From      ( Select    TBL, ID, AGE, DEPT, SALARY, START_DATE, 
                                  Row_Number() OVER(Partition By ID, START_DATE Order By ID, START_DATE, TBL) "RN"
                        From    ( Select        'A' "TBL", ID, AGE, DEPT, SALARY, START_DATE From tbl_a Union All
                                  Select        'B' "TBL", ID, Null, Null, SALARY, START_DATE From tbl_b
                                )
                      ) 
            Where     RN = 1 )
ORDER BY  ID, START_DATE, DEPT
```

... the resulting dataset should be:

```sql
--      ID        AGE DEPT     SALARY START_DATE
--  ------ ---------- ---- ---------- ----------
--       1         30 A          1000 01-JAN-00
--       1         31 B          1200 01-JAN-22
--       1         31 B          1500 01-JUN-22   <-- added row
--       2         25 C          1200 01-JUN-21
--       2         26 A          1300 01-JAN-22
--       3         34 D          1400 01-JAN-21
--       3         34 D          1600 01-JUN-21   <-- added row
--       3         35 C          1800 01-JAN-22
```

... this could be merged into table A to insert the missing rows:

```sql
Merge Into tbl_a a
Using ( ... main sql ... ) x ON(x.ID = a.ID And 
                                x.START_DATE = a.START_DATE) 
When Not Matched
Then  INSERT (a.ID, a.AGE, a.DEPT, a.SALARY, a.START_DATE) 
      Values (x.ID, x.AGE, x.DEPT, x.SALARY, x.START_DATE)
```

Note: ON clause should be adjusted (probably) to ensure unique row addressing in your table A.